# How can I count the number of channel entries that have parents?

Tags: relationships, count, parent

We are a non-profit organization with many volunteers that we assign to various volunteer roles.  I created a Volunteers channel and a Roles channel, and in the Roles channel I set up a relationship field called role_membership where I can add all of the volunteers in the role.  So, I might have a role titled Website Developer, and select John Doe and Jane Smith in the role_membership field.  In this way, many volunteers will be assigned to roles, but we also have new volunteers that have not been assigned a role yet.

What I want to do is to count the number of entries in the Volunteers channel that have been associated with at least one role (i.e., that have a parent in the Roles channel, role_membership field).  I can't figure out how to alter the exp:channel:entries tag to get this count directly.  Instead I've tried using PHP, but that is not working well.  The following code will work IF I use limit="50" to set a low limit on the number of channel entries returned.  But, if I set limit="2000" to get the count I need, I get a PHP out of memory error.

`<?php $assigned_volunteers=0; ?>
{exp:channel:entries channel="volunteers" limit="50"}
  {parents field="role_membership"}
    {if {parents:total_results}>0}<?php $assigned_volunteers+=1; ?>{/if}
  {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}`

Is there a way to obtain the count of volunteers assigned to roles directly by altering the exp:channel:entries tag?

Comment: Is this data you are trying to get for personal use, or to actually display it on the front end?

Comment: I want to display it on the front end, but if that is difficult or impossible, I would settle for getting the data for personal use.